# Move C-style array into `xt::array` from xtensor

Tags: c++, arrays, xtensor

I am using [stb image library](https://github.com/nothings/stb) to load a image into C-style contiguous array. I want to move this array into a `xtensor` style `xtensor` or `xarray` with `xt::adapt`. Here is the demonstration code:

```cpp
// It must be C-stype array because stb is C library.
std::size_t size = 24;
unsigned char arr_1d[size];
for (auto i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
  arr_1d[i] = i + 1;
}

// Convert 1D array with 24 elements into (3, 2, 4) xtensor.
auto img = xt::adapt(arr_1d, xt::xshape<3, 2, 4>(), xt::no_ownership());
```

But I kept getting the error:

```
test_xtensor.cpp:16:14: error: no matching function for call to 'adapt'
  auto img = xt::adapt(arr_1d, xt::xshape<3, 2, 4>(), xt::no_ownership());
             ^~~~~~~~~
/tmp/xtensor-install/include/xtensor/xadapt.hpp:85:5: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with L = xt::layout_type::row_major]: variably modified type 'unsigned char (&)[size]' cannot be used as a template argument
    adapt(C&& container, const SC& shape, layout_type l = L)
```

Is it possible to achieve the above task with C-style array or I must convert to C++ vector first?

Comment: looks like you don't need `xt::no_ownership()` for a stack allocated array https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/adaptor.html#adapting-stack-allocated-arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following compiles:

```
auto img = xt::adapt((char *)arr_1d, xt::xshape<3, 2, 4>());
```

As I understand the documentation, it ought to work without the cast, but I get the following error about that candidate not being considered: (Clang 14 on macOS)

```
/opt/homebrew/include/xtensor/xadapt.hpp:458:17: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'T[N]' against 'unsigned char[size]'
    inline auto adapt(T (&c_array)[N], const SC& shape, layout_type l = L)
```

Comment: I also think `xt::adapt(arr_1d, xt::xshape<3, 2, 4>());` should work because `arr_1d` is already the address of the first element of the array `arr_1d`.

Comment: Yes, that is what the second part of my question states. "without the cast".

Comment: `cosntexpr std::size_t size=24;` will work. You are using a none standard extension called *VLA* right now. Making `size` a compile-time constant will remove the problem.

Comment: Oh, well spotted! I did not connect the two.